# Is there a way to set the value of hash key to the value of a key in Redis

Tags: redis, hashmap

Consider I have a key PREMIUM_PRICE,

SET PREMIUM_PRICE "1000"

Now, I want PRODUCT_A's price to be same as PREMIUM_PRICE. I don't want to say,

- HSET PRODUCT_A PRICE "1000" (because If PREMIUM_PRICE value changes I want PRODUCT_A's price to get updated automatically)

**OR**

- HSET PRODUCT_A PRICE "PREMIUM_PRICE", so that I have to get price value of PRODUCT_A which itself is a key in redis containing the actual price as its value.(because I don't want to make a second query to get the value of PREMIUM_KEY)

Can I say something like,

HSET PRODUCT_A PRICE **[value(PREMIUM_PRICE)]**

,where **[value(PREMIUM_PRICE)]** is the link to PREMIUM_PRICE key or whatever

so that when I do a HGET PRODUCT_A PRICE, redis automatically returns the latest value of PREMIUM_PRICE.

Is this possible. Somebody tell me.

Comment: You could make a custom command (lua script) that did the indirect lookup for you, but I don't think Redis has a way of storing the reference as some kind of special value.

Answer (score 0):

In general **yes**, you can. But you should use LUA scripting for that because of redis do not have that built in functionality.

So you function would look`s like

```
local hsetValue = redis.call("hget", ARGV[1], ARGV[2]);
if hsetValue then
   return redis.call("get", hsetValue);
end

return nil;
```

So you can use that LUA function to get `HSET` field value based on value of other key.